# SQL Server compatibility issue help

Tags: sql-server

I have an application that's in the deployment phase. I used Visual Studio 2015 and LocalDb for my application. When I converted it to an installer for a 32-bit machine and installed it on a 32-bit machine, the interface runs fine, but there's an error. It goes something like: "**The database cannot be opened because it is version 852. This version supports 782.**" I have searched for three days for solutions and one I found recommended having the database server the same for all machines. I can't do that because my machine is 32-bit and can't install any 64-bit applications and software. My plan is to lower the version of LocalDb in the machine where I have made the application. I don't know how to do that yet though. Is this procedure good? If not, are there any other alternatives? What should I install? Client PC is also 32-bit.  Are there any helpful solutions?

**What I've tried:** 
 1. I tried to install LocalDB 2014 x86 on my 64-bit PC so that I can make a database that's also compatible with a 32-bit PC.  Sadly, it didn't work because LocalDB 2014 x86 isn't compatible with my 64-bit PC.

 2. Attempted to uninstall SQL Server 2016 but it won't uninstall.
 
 3. Installed SQL Server 2014 on my machine, but still had no effect.

Comment: How were you able to develop a SQL Server 2016 database (852) on a 32-bit OS? AFAIK, SQL Server 2016 is only 64-bit. That said, it shouldn't matter if you use a 32 or 64 database engine but you can't deploy using attach or restore to an earlier SQL version. You ought to be able to use SQL Server 2014 on a 32-bit box for development. Are you perhaps using a 64-bit build machine with SQL 2016 installed?